# Android : first listview item show 1dp border but other items shows border 2dp

Tags: android, android-layout, listview, android-listview

I create some listview item with an adapter from a item xml file.
I have added a thin border on the top of a layout.

In my listview, the first item is OK, with a border = 1dp, but for others items, the border is more big : 2p..

Where is the problem ?

Here is the code all_annonces_item.xml :

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="120dp"
    android:layout_margin="10dp"
    android:background="@color/bg_listview_all"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/allannonces_image"
        android:layout_width="80dp"
        android:layout_height="80dp"
        android:background="@drawable/bg_top_and_left"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
        android:src="@drawable/test2" />

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="80dp"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/allannonces_image"
        android:background="@drawable/bg_top_and_right"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/allannonces_titre"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="10dp"
            android:text="TextView"
            android:textColor="#666666"
            android:textSize="14sp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/allannonces_categorie"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:text="TextView"
            android:textColor="#9A9A9A"
            android:textSize="12sp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/allannonces_prix"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
            android:text="TextView"
            android:textColor="#6EA601"
            android:textSize="12sp" />

    </RelativeLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="33dp"
        android:layout_below="@id/allannonces_image"
        android:background="@drawable/bg_linearlayout" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/allannonces_imageuser"
            android:layout_width="15dp"
            android:layout_height="15dp"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:src="@drawable/avatar5" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/allannonces_pseudo_user"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@id/allannonces_imageuser"
            android:text="TextView"
            android:textSize="10sp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/allannonces_ville"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
            android:text="TextView"
            android:textSize="10sp" />

    </RelativeLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

And the code of the impacted xml file bg_top_and_right.xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
  <item> 
    <shape android:shape="rectangle">
      <solid android:color="#E3E3E1" /> 
    </shape>
  </item>   
    <item android:top="1dp"  android:right="1dp" >  
     <shape android:shape="rectangle"> 
      <solid android:color="@color/blanc" />
    </shape>
   </item>
 </layer-list>
```

And finally, the code of my adapter :

```
public class AllAnnonces_custom_adapter extends ArrayAdapter<Annonce> {

    Typeface robotolight = Typeface.createFromAsset(getContext().getAssets(), "fonts/Roboto-Light.ttf");
    Typeface robotoBold = Typeface.createFromAsset(getContext().getAssets(), "fonts/Roboto-Bold.ttf");
    Typeface robotoRegular = Typeface.createFromAsset(getContext().getAssets(), "fonts/Roboto-Regular.ttf");

    public AllAnnonces_custom_adapter(Activity activity, List<Annonce> annonces) {
        super(activity, 0, annonces);
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        ViewHolderItem viewHolder;

        if (convertView == null) {
            Activity activity = (Activity) getContext();
            // inflate the layout
            LayoutInflater inflater = activity.getLayoutInflater();
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.all_annonces_item, parent, false);
            // well set up the ViewHolder
            viewHolder = new ViewHolderItem();
            viewHolder.imageAnnonce = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.allannonces_image) ;
            viewHolder.titre = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.allannonces_titre);
            viewHolder.villeObj = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.allannonces_ville);
            viewHolder.prix = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.allannonces_prix);   
            viewHolder.pseudoUser = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.allannonces_pseudo_user);  
            viewHolder.categorie = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.allannonces_categorie);
            viewHolder.imageUser = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.allannonces_imageuser) ;

            // store the holder with the view.
            convertView.setTag(viewHolder);

        } else {
            viewHolder = (ViewHolderItem) convertView.getTag();
        }

        Annonce annonce = getItem(position);

        if (annonce != null) {

            DisplayImageOptions options = new DisplayImageOptions.Builder()
            .cacheInMemory(true)
            .cacheOnDisc(true)
            .build();

            ImageLoaderConfiguration config = new ImageLoaderConfiguration.Builder(getContext())
            .defaultDisplayImageOptions(options)
            .threadPriority(Thread.MAX_PRIORITY)
            .denyCacheImageMultipleSizesInMemory()
            .memoryCacheSize(2 * 1024 * 1024)
            .build();

            ImageLoader imageLoader = ImageLoader.getInstance();
            imageLoader.init(config); 
            imageLoader.displayImage(annonce.getImage(), viewHolder.imageAnnonce);

            String imageUser = annonce.getImageUser();
            if (imageUser.equals("avatar1")) {
                viewHolder.imageUser.setImageResource(R.drawable.avatar1) ;
            }
            else if (imageUser.equals("avatar2")) {
                viewHolder.imageUser.setImageResource(R.drawable.avatar2) ;
            }
            else if (imageUser.equals("avatar3")) {
                viewHolder.imageUser.setImageResource(R.drawable.avatar3) ;
            }
            else if (imageUser.equals("avatar4")) {
                viewHolder.imageUser.setImageResource(R.drawable.avatar4) ;
            }
            else if (imageUser.equals("avatar5")) {
                viewHolder.imageUser.setImageResource(R.drawable.avatar5) ;
            }
            else if (imageUser.equals("avatar6")) {
                viewHolder.imageUser.setImageResource(R.drawable.avatar6) ;
            }
            else {
                viewHolder.imageUser.setImageResource(R.drawable.avatar1) ;
            }

            viewHolder.titre.setText(annonce.getTitle());
            viewHolder.titre.setTypeface(robotoRegular);

            viewHolder.pseudoUser.setText(annonce.getPseudoUser());
            viewHolder.pseudoUser.setTypeface(robotoRegular);

            viewHolder.categorie.setText(annonce.getCategorie());
            viewHolder.categorie.setTypeface(robotoRegular);

            viewHolder.villeObj.setText(annonce.getVilleObjet());
            viewHolder.villeObj.setTypeface(robotoRegular);

            viewHolder.prix.setText(annonce.getPrix());
            viewHolder.prix.setText("€" + annonce.getPrix() + ",00 EUR");
            viewHolder.prix.setTypeface(robotoRegular);
        }

        return convertView;

    }

    static class ViewHolderItem {
        ImageView imageAnnonce;
        ImageView imageUser;
        TextView titre;
        TextView villeObj;
        TextView pseudoUser;
        TextView prix;
        TextView categorie;
    }


}
```

Comment: I thing that the problem is in the divider of your listView, please show the xml of your listView , to remove the pading set the size of the divider in your list to 0dp .

Comment: Howww !! You are so best @wSakly ! It was a problem combined using a fixed height of RelativeLayout in my item xml. Now i use `android:divider="@android:color/transparent"` and `android:dividerHeight="10.0sp"` to fix the space between my items. Thanks a lot !